# Kubespray ansible extra args for pods specifications are not deployed on the target k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubespray

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/vars.md), Extra flags for the API server, controller, and scheduler components can be specified using the variables below, in the form of dicts of key-value pairs of configuration parameters that will be inserted into the kubeadm YAML config file:

- ***kube_kubeadm_apiserver_extra_args***
- ***kube_kubeadm_controller_extra_args***
- ***kube_kubeadm_scheduler_extra_args***

But I can't really figure out where to add them in ansible playbooks so that they can be rendered on the master node during the cluster deloyment.

I tried using this file `kubespray/roles/kubernetes/master/defaults/main/main.yml` and this file `kubespray/roles/kubespray-defaults/defaults/main.yaml` but it doesn't work for none of the two files, ansible doesn't deploy them, like if ansible doesn't read them.

Where the `kubeadm` YAML config file is located?

Can someone here help with these parameters management?

Answer (score 1):

As documented on https://kubespray.io/#/docs/ansible?id=group-vars-and-overriding-variables-precedence, you should take a look at `inventory/<mycluster>/group_vars/all/all.yml` and `inventory/<mycluster>/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml` for the configuration of your cluster.

Where `inventory/<mycluster>` is a copy of the kubespray provided [`inventory/sample` folder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/tree/master/inventory/sample) with adaptations of the `inventory.ini` file and files inside `group_vars`.

Kubespray use the inventory layout proposed in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/sample_setup.html#alternative-directory-layout

Whatever your layout, for group_vars to be loaded, the have to be in the same folder as the file referenced by the `--inventory-file/--inventory/-i` option or `defaults.inventory` config.

For example, if your inventory is the file `config/inventory`, you need to copy the sample inventory group_vars in `config/group_vars`.

Comment: @zigam, I've read the documentation and see those files under the `kubespray` directory, but I'm not sure where and how ansible read and use them  in the kubespray context. I already have an inventory file containing nodes and their IP that is specified in my `ansible.cfg` to be used by `ansible-playbook`.

Please when and how the files you mentioned above come into the play? what is the purpose of 'mycluster` here? I'm a litte bit lost, please can you give me more precision on how to get my master components arguments overridden with `kubeadm extra args`?

Comment: Ansible inventory contains multiple parts: listing of machines with grouping (ini file), variables for groups (in `group_vars/<group-name>/<whatever>.yml` and variables for machines (in `host_vars/<inventory_hostname>/<whatever>.yml`. When referencing an inventory file, ansible automatically loads the group_vars and host_vars from the same directory as the inventory ini file. You can check the result of inventory loading with the command `ansible-inventory --graph --vars`

Comment: I've put my kubeadm extra args here : `kubespray/inventory/local/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml`. I run the playbook like this `ansible-playbook -l k8s-cluster -I config/inventory playbooks/k8s-cluster.yml` 
Here `config/inventory` is the file containing my hosts inventory.
The master configuration is style not deployed. 
I'm wondering how kubespray uses these variables in the deployment process.

Also it seems like in the previous versions of kubespray, setting these kubeadm exra arags in this file  : `kubespray/roles/kubernetes/master/defaults/main/main.yml` worked.

Comment: As said in my previous comment: the `group_vars` has to be in the same directory as the referenced inventory, ansible won't load group_vars from another folder. I updated my answer.